# How to display lable to a url cell in LWC datatable?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to build a datatable in lwc and one of the column's datatype is url. When I provide URL it shows as https://www.google.com , what I want is just label "Google.com".

I can see from the docs of the [data table](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) , i can use `typeAttributes` for url and provide "label", "target" and it should be good to go.

But when I try that I get cell as `http://[object Object]` which is a bit weird.

[image]

Template.html :

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
            A data table that fetches content during initialization.
        </h2>

        <!-- Simple -->
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                is-loading={tableLoadingState}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS :

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'createdDate' , type: 'date-local',typeAttributes :{ month: "2-digit",day: "2-digit"}},
    { label: 'Duplicate Website', fieldName: 'duplicateWebsite', type: 'url'  },
    { label: 'Person Detail Match', fieldName: 'personDetailMatch', type: 'boolean' }

];

export default class DatatableBasic extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columns;
    @track tableLoadingState = true;

     connectedCallback() {
        const data =  [{createdDate : "1479944705000" , duplicateWebsite : { label : 'Google' , target : 'www.google.com'}   , personDetailMatch : true }];
        this.data = data;
        this.tableLoadingState = false;
    }
}
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/vi7rAWnIH/5/edit

**Update:** I managed to update label by providing label fieldName in column definition

```
 const columns = [
        { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'createdDate' , type: 'date-local',typeAttributes :{ month: "2-digit",day: "2-digit"}},
        { label: 'Duplicate Website', fieldName: 'duplicateWebsite', type: 'url',typeAttributes: { label: {fieldName:'duplicateWebsite'}, value: {fieldName:'urlTarget'}  }  },
        { label: 'Person Detail Match', fieldName: 'personDetailMatch', type: 'boolean' }



];
```

And rowData as

```
const data =  [{personName:"url name", createdDate : "1479944705000" , duplicateWebsite : "Google"  ,urlTarget : "www.google.com",  personDetailMatch : true }];
```

Now the issue is it takes label value as href value, thus making links dead.

Updated Playground Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/vi7rAWnIH/16/edit

Comment: Probably due to the fact that datatable accepts single level JSON, the title and target should be on root level. Such that `column.fieldName` maps directly with `data.fieldName`

Comment: @Raul can you give an example? or update the playground code snippet?

Comment: Here is an example: [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/vi7rAWnIH/7/edit)

Comment: Hi @Raul , Am sorry if my question was not clear. It's showing the whole URL (`http://www.google.com` ), all i want is to show just the label as `google`. anc hyperlink to actual url

Comment: My fault, had not read properly, didn't start with a coffee today :)

Comment: so is this question resolved?

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni i managed to have dynamic label value, but then it makes the links dead as its putting same in href.

Comment: specifying the value in typeAttributes doesn't do anything right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use typeAttribute object in URL column. I tried to use JS object but couldn't use JS object in typeAttribute in datatable. So, my finding was that your label should be a field in each entry in data list.
Try this playground version of your code: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/vi7rAWnIH/20/edit

Issue with your version of code which is rendering label as target is there is no value attribute in typeAttribute object. It's correct name is target. Screenshot from lightning-datatable documentation:
[image]

Codet snippet in case playground is not available:

JS data array:

```
const data =  [{createdDate : "1479944705000" , duplicateWebsite : "www.google.com", websiteLabel:"google", personDetailMatch : true }];
```

datatable column definition:

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'createdDate' , type: 'date-local',typeAttributes :{ month: "2-digit",day: "2-digit"}},
    { label: 'Duplicate Website', fieldName: 'duplicateWebsite', type: 'url' , typeAttributes:{label: { fieldName: 'websiteLabel' }}},
    { label: 'Person Detail Match', fieldName: 'personDetailMatch', type: 'boolean' } 
];
```

Comment: Amazing. Can you add relevant code snippets in the answer in case the playground link dies?

Comment: If you want to open the link in new window you can use the below :  { label: 'Duplicate Website', fieldName: 'urlTarget', type: "url",typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'duplicateWebsite' }, target: '_blank'}}